# Rxjs operator: filter array of array

Tags: filter, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have an observable which contains an array of object arrays. For example the pseudocode below

```
observable = Observable([[object1, object2], [object3, object4],[object5], [object6]]])
```

Now, I want to map through the arrays and check if object.name === 'something' and return first occurrence. If no object in a list match, then return undefined. From each array only one object will be returned. So the output will be like `Observable([object2, object3, undefined, object6])`. How can I do this with rxjs operator?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't in a single step. You can use the .map()-operator but you have to filter each array on its own and then return a final array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single operator to do what you are looking for, but maybe something like this could work

```
observable = Observable([[object1, object2], [object3, object4],[object5], [object6]]])

observable.pipe(
  // switchMap so that you move to another observable, which emits on of the contained arrays at the time
  switchMap(arrayOfArrays => from(arrayOfArrays)),
  // map each array to the first occurence of the element you are looking for
  map(array => array.first(el => el.whatever === whateverValue),
  // use toArray to get again an array
  toArray()
)
```

Alternatively you can work with JS Array methods and do something like this

```
observable = Observable([[object1, object2], [object3, object4],[object5], [object6]]])

observable.pipe(
  map(arrayOfArrays => arrayOfArrays.map(
    array => array.first(el => el.whatever === whateverValue))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote example assuming that object is number. you could rewrite it to your case

```
import { from, Observable } from "rxjs";
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";

function findNumber(source: Observable<number[]>, num: number) {
   return source.pipe(
      map( arr => arr.find( n => n===num) )
   )
}

const source = from([[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3], [4, 1], [5, 2]]);
findNumber(source, 1).subscribe(next => console.log(next));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-5a3nwz?file=index.ts